# Remove rows inside txt file - unix

Tags: unix, row, trim, cat

i need to remove some particular rows in a txt files considering a particular value. In particular i need to delete all the rows that cointain this syntax.

```
Row to deleted   
0311MUX                          31.03.2020

In the report i have rows like below one that should not be deleted since after mux i have a code.
0311MUX23453                     31.03.2020
```

Could you please help me on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^0311MUX[[:space:]]/d' w | ed -s file.txt
```

Will delete all rows from the file starting with that string followed by whitespace (to avoid deleting your other row with 0311MUX as a prefix).

Or

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /^0311MUX\b/' file.txt
```